# Adding Filters to imageview

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to ios development and trying to use code filters...

```
imgAnimation=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
imgAnimation.animationImages=_arrimg;
//animationImages=animationImages;
imgAnimation.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

imgAnimation.animationDuration = 2.0f;
imgAnimation.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[imgAnimation startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:imgAnimation];
```

My animation is working properly but how can I apply filters like `sepia, grey scale` I had found many tutorials but they are for single images kindly help ???

Comment: Look at Core Image - its the framework/technology for this.

Comment: What exactly is the problem. You have a single image there, why can't you apply that? Sorry maybe I didn't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: no i have array of images suppose 20 images  which i am animating on runtime and i want to add filter on all those images on runtime

Comment: My Custom Method and One `for loop` that is all what you required...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample Code :**

```
+(UIImage *) applyFilterToImage: (UIImage *)inputImage
{
    CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[inputImage CGImage]];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8], nil];
    CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];

    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
    UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return newImg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to pre load all the images with the filters. Then load them to an array and set it to animationImages property.

For getting the various filters you can refer this project from [github](https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters)

Answer (score 0):

GPU image open source framework for image effects.

[Download the Source Code From Here:-](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

Hope it Helps to You :)